# How to find out where GNU make was started?

Tags: gnu-make

If I start (GNU) make with the -C option, it first cd into that directory and
$(CURDIR) will be set to that. I wonder if there is any mechanism to figure out in the makefile where make was originally invoked from?

That is, if I have a makefile in /some/location:

```
all:
  @echo $(CURDIR)
  @echo $(SOME_MAGIC_VARIABLE_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR)
```

and then I do:

```
$ cd /other/place
$ make -C /some/location
```

I would get

```
/some/location
/other/place
```

printed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such variable in `make`.

However, POSIX shells maintain and export a `PWD` variable to commands that they invoke.  All environment variables are imported by `make` as `make` variables.

So, if you look in the `make` variable `$(PWD)` you will very likely find the original path that the shell that invoked `make` was using.

Comment: Indeed. Works like a charm. Thank you!